# How can I retrieve the count of a certain character in a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have this code to try to get a count of how many of the passed-in characters occurs in a string array:

```
string[] doc1StrArray;
. . .
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(string CharToCount)
{
    int count = 0;
    count = doc1StrArray.Count(f => f == CharToCount);
    return count;
}
```

...called like so:

```
iCountOfCommasInDoc1 = GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(",");
```

...but it doesn't work. It finds no commas, for example, in the following case, although the document certainly does contain commas.

[image]

### UPDATE

Both are working - Roman's suggestion and Teroneko's:

```
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacterInDoc1(char CharToCount)
{
    return doc1StrArray.Sum(s => s.Count(c => c == CharToCount));
}

private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacterInDoc2(char CharToCount)
{
    return doc2StrArray.SelectMany(x => x).Count(c => c == CharToCount);
}
```

...but I don't know which one is better/more efficient.

Comment: You are comparing the string against the character if I am not mistaken. You'll need to check against every character in each string in your array

Comment: Maybe also: `return string.Join("", doc1StrArray).Aggregate(0, (i, c) => c.Equals(CharToCount) ? ++i : i);`

Answer (score 5):

```
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(char charToCount)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var word in doc1StrArray)
        foreach (char character in word)
           if (character == charToCount)
               count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Most efficient way among all answers

Answer (score 4):

@Jawad is right. You can do something like this to accomplimish your goal:

```
var count = doc1StrArray.SelectMany(x => x).Count(c => c == CharToCount);
```

This selects any character in each array item and returns them as one `IEnumerable<char>`. When you know apply `.Count(..)` on it, you are counting against each character.

**Edit**:
I made some tests and it seems that the for-loop is the fastest

```cs
        public int GetAmountOfChar(string[] strings, char character) {
            int amountOfChar = 0;
            var linesLength = strings.Length;
            for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < linesLength; lineIndex++)
            {
                var line = TextExample[lineIndex];
                var charsLength = line.Length;
                for (var charIndex = 0; charIndex < charsLength; charIndex++)
                    if (line[charIndex] == character)
                        amountOfChar++;
            }
            return amountOfChar;
        }
```

but not the foreach-loop:

```
[TestSelectManyCount] Found 5861172 characters in 3295,8278ms
[TestForForIncrement] Found 5861172 characters in 377,0376ms
[TestForCount] Found 5861172 characters in 1064,9164ms
[TestForEachWhileIndexOfIncrement] Found 5861172 characters in 1550,894ms
[TestForEachForEachIncrement] Found 5861172 characters in 473,4347ms
[TestSumCounts] Found 5861172 characters in 1062,2644ms
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow._62505315
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        public const char CharToBeFound = 'a';
        public const int Iterations = 5000;

        static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestSelectManyCount();
            TestForForIncrement();
            TestForCount();
            TestForEachWhileIndexOfIncrement();
            TestForEachForEachIncrement();
            TestSumCounts();
        }

        public static void TestSelectManyCount()
        {
            var iterations = Iterations;
            int amountOfChar = 0;
            stopWatch.Start();
            checked
            {
                while (iterations-- >= 0)
                {
                    amountOfChar += TextExample.SelectMany(x => x).Count(c => c == CharToBeFound);
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(TestSelectManyCount)}] Found {amountOfChar} characters in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }

        public static void TestForForIncrement()
        {
            var iterations = Iterations;
            int amountOfChar = 0;
            stopWatch.Start();
            checked
            {
                while (iterations-- >= 0)
                {
                    var linesLength = TextExample.Length;
                    for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < linesLength; lineIndex++)
                    {
                        var line = TextExample[lineIndex];
                        var charsLength = line.Length;
                        for (var charIndex = 0; charIndex < charsLength; charIndex++)
                            if (line[charIndex] == CharToBeFound)
                                amountOfChar++;
                    }
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(TestForForIncrement)}] Found {amountOfChar} characters in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }

        public static void TestForCount()
        {
            var iterations = Iterations;
            var amountOfChar = 0;
            stopWatch.Start();
            checked
            {
                while (iterations-- >= 0)
                {
                    var lineLength = TextExample.Length;
                    for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lineLength; lineIndex++)
                    {
                        amountOfChar += TextExample[lineIndex].Count(c => c == CharToBeFound);
                    }
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(TestForCount)}] Found {amountOfChar} characters in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }

        public static void TestForEachWhileIndexOfIncrement()
        {
            var iterations = Iterations;
            var amountOfChar = 0;
            stopWatch.Start();
            checked
            {
                while (iterations-- >= 0)
                {
                    foreach (string word in TextExample)
                    {
                        int startIndex = 0;
                        int charIndex = 0;
                        while ((charIndex = word.IndexOf(CharToBeFound, startIndex)) != -1)
                        {
                            startIndex = charIndex + 1;
                            amountOfChar++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(TestForEachWhileIndexOfIncrement)}] Found {amountOfChar} characters in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }

        public static void TestForEachForEachIncrement()
        {
            var iterations = Iterations;
            int amountOfChar = 0;
            stopWatch.Start();
            checked
            {
                while (iterations-- >= 0)
                {
                    foreach (var word in TextExample)
                        foreach (char character in word)
                            if (character == CharToBeFound)
                                amountOfChar++;
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(TestForEachForEachIncrement)}] Found {amountOfChar} characters in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }

        public static void TestSumCounts()
        {
            var iterations = Iterations;
            int amountOfChar = 0;
            stopWatch.Start();
            checked
            {
                while (iterations-- >= 0)
                {
                    amountOfChar += TextExample.Sum(s => s.Count(c => c == CharToBeFound));
                }
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"[{nameof(TestSumCounts)}] Found {amountOfChar} characters in {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
            stopWatch.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

For my surprise I also found a reference [here](https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-count-number-times-character-occurs-string) that does underline the fact, that the for-loop is outscaling the foreach-loop

Comment: With this also I get "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'"

Comment: I had to assume that CharToCount is a character: `char CharToCount = 'b'`, and doc1StrArrayis an array of character enumerables (something like char[]): `string[] arrays = new string[] { "testa", "testb" }`. Please provide us the full code, then we can help concretely.

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample of what you can use to iterate over an array of strings to check the number of times a character appears in the string and then sum it all up.

```
string[] test = new string[] { 
    "This is, the first test string", 
    "This, is the second, test string", 
    "this is the, third"};

string inp = ",";
Console.WriteLine(test.Sum(stringItem => stringItem.Count(charItem => charItem.ToString().Equals(inp))));

// Prints 4
```

During the comparison, you can convert the character being iterated to a string for a proper `string.Equals(string)` comparison. Reason you want to convert it to a string is because character 'a' is Not equal to a string "a". If you want to do a character comparison, see the character compare method below (but note characters should be compared with characters and strings with strings.).

This can be your method to count,

```
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(string CharToCount)
{
    return doc1StrArray.Sum(stringItem => stringItem.Count(charItem => charItem.ToString().Equals(CharToCount)));
}

// And this one to use for Character Comparisons using `.ToCharArray()` method. 
// You can parse each character as well by the use of char.Parse(str)
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(string CharToCount)
{
    return test.Sum(stringItem => stringItem.ToCharArray().Count(charItem => charItem.Equals(CharToCount.ToCharArray().First())));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or like this

```
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(string[] doc1StrArray, char charToCount)
{
    int count = 0;
    count = doc1StrArray.Sum(s => s.Count(c => c == charToCount));
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I get "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon have you changed `CharToCount` type to `char`?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement with parallel linq.

```
    public static int GetBounty(string[] gettysburgLines, char c)
    {
        int count = 0;
        gettysburgLines.AsParallel().ForAll(line => {
            int q = line.AsParallel().Where(a => a == c).Count();
            count += q;
        });
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of Regex:

```
private int GetCountOfSpecificCharacter(string CharToCount)
{
    return Regex.Matches(string.join("", doc1StrArray), CharToCount).Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just use :

```
var ad = Array.FindAll(yourArray,u=>u.Equals(passedChar).Length
```